# Sorting from current point to end of file in gvim?

Tags: vim

The following in command mode (gvim)

```
:.,G!sort
```

results in

```
E464: Ambiguous use of user defined-command

:help E464
```

```
  Ambiguous use of user-defined command

There are two user-defined commands with a common name prefix, and you used
Command-line completion to execute one of them. |user-cmd-ambiguous|
Example: >
    :command MyCommand1 echo "one"
    :command MyCommand2 echo "two"
    :MyCommand

  Not an editor command
```

I have stared at this for a little while can someone throw a bone my way or offer a way to do this without resorting to visual mode?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I usually use `:.,$!sort`; does that work for you?

**Original Poster Edit**

G is not the proper range specification.  From the :help range output see below.

```
Line numbers may be specified with:     *:range* *E14* *{address}*
    {number}    an absolute line number
    .       the current line              *:.*
    $       the last line in the file         *:$*
    %       equal to 1,$ (the entire file)        *:%*
    't      position of mark t (lowercase)        *:'*
    'T      position of mark T (uppercase); when the mark is in
            another file it cannot be used in a range
    /{pattern}[/]   the next line where {pattern} matches     *:/*
    ?{pattern}[?]   the previous line where {pattern} matches *:?*
    \/      the next line where the previously used search
            pattern matches
    \?      the previous line where the previously used search
            pattern matches
    \&      the next line where the previously used substitute
            pattern matches

Each may be followed (several times) by '+' or '-' and an optional number.
This number is added or subtracted from the preceding line number.  If the
number is omitted, 1 is used.
```

Comment: Riddle me this Batman: how does one do "!{motion}{filter}"? None of these work: !Gsort ... !G,sort ... !G sort

Comment: Wait, it works in vim too! :-P (At least my version thereof.)

Comment: Not in vim 7.2.22 on my Mac, apparently. I get "Gsort: command not found" from the shell. OK, at least I'm not a dunce!

Comment: I think the motion has to come before the ! and that was what I was intending to do.  But I was mixing up motions and ranges.  :!Gsort results in Gsort not found (as expected by me).  :G!sort leads to the ambigous thing above.

Comment: @Chris what version of vim are you using?

Comment: @John: If you're doing the !motion thing, don't type the colon! You have to put the ! in vi mode, not ex mode! (The latter expects a range.)

Comment: @ojblass: I'm using vim 7.2 that comes with Ubuntu 9.04.

Comment: I am on the same but here the help about shows version 7.2.79

Answer (score 5):

G is a motion, not a range specifier. See `:help range`.

Answer (score 0):

```
" vim has internal sort
:.,$sort

"if has numbers use
:.,$sort n

"to delete duplicated lines
:.,$sort u

" read :h sort
```